# The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized - IIS Upgrade - WebService & Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, iis

I know there were few questions has already on this topic. Please note that this question and situation is different compared to others. Ofcourse, I have tried all other directions gave in previous questions.

**Previous Scenario:**
My current server is 2003 and its having a web application hosted in it. And a web service hosted in 2008 server. Both are working in Windows Authentication. Still now, its working fine without any issues.

**Upgradation Scenario:**
We are planning to upgrade the server from 2003 to 2008 for web application hosted box.

**Issue:**
After we upgraded, we are getting below error.

> *The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized*

When we set **Anonymous Authentication** its working as expected.

Code has already **set up with defaultcredential as True**.

One tough part is : **We are unable to change the code as its build in .Net Framework 2.0** as its having lot of internal DLLs missing/not working/not in proper condition to take and fix it. Its almost having 116 project linked together so we dont have enough time to fix and rebuild all the things.

Below are the snippets:

Language: C#
.Net Framework: 2.0
Authentication : Windows

I have tried all authorization, modifying web config files, roles setting in IIS etc., nothing has helped me. And also i have tried all tricks given in this site but nothing helps out. Please let me know if there is anything I can do.

TA
VIRA

Comment: Where is the 401 generated? When the user tries to go to the site or when the site tries to use the service?

Comment: when the site tries to use the service... I have tried using dummy applicaiton, its working from my localhost. but when the deployed application (from server 2008), lead to this error.

Comment: Have you made sure the win auth feature is installed in the server. I have faced same issue when upgrading. In modern win server OS we need to explicitly install win auth.

Comment: Does your application pool identity has access to the physical path of website?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't provide enougth information, but I'll try to help.

Enable the failed-request tracing module:

http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85